# Regulate speed of game with speed of screen touches

Tags: java, android, performance, touch

I am creating a game where the user must tap the screen faster to allow them to go faster in game, however I have encountered some problems. I have made the game so it calculates the amount of taps per minute from the users last tap and their current tap, however this method seems to be jerky and does not work too well. I also cannot work out another way to do it, so that the when they don't tap at all, it slows down.

How would I go about creating this mechanism for the game where the faster the user taps, the faster the game goes, and if they don't tap at all it slows to a stop.

Thanks

Here is a snippet of what I have so far, calculating the Taps Per Minute (TPM) of the user. (This is in the on touch method). I am currently passing the TPM into an update method which moves the background by TPM/100 each time it updates (it's running at 30FPS)

```
 if (thisTouch == 0 || lastTouch == 0) {
            Log.d("info","First Touch");
            thisTouch = lastTouch = System.currentTimeMillis();
        } else {
            Log.d("d","touch");
            thisTouch = System.currentTimeMillis();

            long difference = thisTouch - lastTouch;

            TPM = (int)((1000*60)/difference);

            lastTouch = thisTouch;
        }
```

I would like to know how I can change this so that the game speeds up when they click faster, and then slows when they do not touch the screen.

Comment: Just to know what you have, could I see your algorithm?

Comment: @Addison - Edited to show what I have so far

Comment: Why not just calculate the "game speed" based on the difference itself? Use it as a multiplier, up to a point, to calculate the speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could do something like this:

- Create a PriorityQueue< Long>
- Whenever the user taps the screen, add (currentTime + someTimeOut) to the queue
- Whenever you are going to check the current speed (eg size of queue), first remove all elements > currentTime.

Don't forget to add appropriate thread safety measures if you do something like this of course.

Comment: Hello. I have 'sort of' used this method, but thank you for bringing it up as it has brought me to an algorithm which has worked. I simply used a Queue<Long>, and everytime the user presses it adds the time they pressed to the queue. I then used Peek() to check if the head of the queue is 1s ago, and if it is, I used Poll(). Once this is done for all items that are >1s ago, (using a while loop) I got the size of the Queue<Long> and passed it into my update method.

Comment: @TomRichardson: You're welcome. Don't forget to upvote helpful answers and maybe accept the best one.

Comment: Done, thank you :) (and sorry, I always forget to upvote and things as a immediately jump straight back into my code!)

Answer (score 0):

Not to be "that guy" but it sounds like your current plan of taps per minute is pretty good but just implemented badly. However, I would strongly recommend a smaller time quantity such as taps per three seconds since games are usually fast paced and having to wait a whole minute to see your character speed up or slow down may produce a sense of delayed lag.

Alternatively, you could could use some form of acceleration that is increased up to a maximum limit every time the screen is tapped and decreases over the time as the screen is not tapped.

Now that I see you updated your question with some code, I'd like to point out that a tap is a touch and release from the screen not necessarily a touch. I honestly don't know from your code whether or not you're compensating for this so this may be the source of some of your problems.

Lastly, for game development algorithms and theory you may want to see this StackExchange site: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

It sounds like you're very close to getting your game to feel the way you want it to, good luck!

Comment: Thankyou very much, I never knew about that part of the website! I'll take a look now :)

Comment: @TomRichardson I added a paragraph because I saw you updated your question with a little bit of code. And your very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Your general approach is pretty much the only way to do it, it just needs some fine tuning.

Keep a general TapsPerTime variable. With each new tap you register, do not *replace* the TapsPerTime, but calculate a new, weighted value:

TapsPerTime = (TapsPerTime * X) + (MeasureTapsPerTime * (1-X))

The factor X you need to find empirically (by trying out what works best for you). The general idea here is that each measurement will only nudge the used value a bit into the right direction.

Also, if you do not detect a tap for a set amount of time, simply update the TapsPerTime with the same formula, but use 0 (zero) for MeasureTapsPerTime. So if the user does not do anything the value goes down.